# I get an error when I try to get the number of array from user, and i need it in normal way without array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << " enter the size of the array ";
    cin >> x;

    int  numbers[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter array value : ";
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this code is not run in visual studio 2019 but run in codeBlocks.
just i need to take x from user.

Comment: `int numbers[x];` --> `std::vector<int> numbers(x);`

Comment: This is not standard C++. In C++, the size of all arrays must be fixed and specified at compile time, not run time.

Comment: Please post the error message along with the question.